# how to call my transferFrom function in web3js?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethers.js

how to call the transferFrom function in web3.js without node.js, Provide code as explanation.

Comment: Please try to describe what's your problem exactly. What did you try and what didn't work. The web3js documentation has everything you need to use it https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/.

Comment: My main question is how do i use web3.js without node.js its hard to find it on the internet. @Ismael

Comment: Do you want to use it from a webpage? Did you try another language like python? You could program web3js from a browser, using remix for example without node. I don't understand what's the problem calling `transferFrom` should be exactly the same if you are using node or not.

Comment: am using it in my html file not remix, I want to call my method from text/javascript in html script example: <script type = "text/javascript"></script>.